# Connection between the words Apollo, Apollyon, and Apologise

Tags: etymology, greek

I've tried researching this topic before, in re Apollo, the Greek god son of Leto and Zeus and twin brother of Artemis, and its possible connection with the "angel of the bottomless pit" as referenced in Revelation 9:11.

Some sources seem to agree that there is some connection with the god apollo, if nothing more than an orthographic one, (pardon my Greek but,) Apollyon apparently means "destruction, or destructor", if and to what extent, Apollo means the same thing, I still have not received a satisfactory answer.  (The coincidence seems too strong to me to brush over completely).

Does anyone know what if anything, the Greek suffix (if it even is a suffix) *-ion* or  *-yon* mean?  My gut feeling is they are indeed related, but having nothing more than my "gut feeling" to go by, I have let this inquiry drop for now, up until a couple of days ago I came across this passage from Herodotus Book 1, chapter CXXXIX:

> their names, which agree with the nature 
>   of their persons and their nobility, all end in the 
>   same letter, that which the Dorians call san, and the 
>   lonians sigma ; you shall find, if you search, that not 
>   some but all Persian names alike end in this letter.

and a little bit latter in chapter CXLI:

> 141. As soon as the Lydians had been subdued by 
>        the Persians, the lonians and Aeolians sent messengers to Cyrus, offering to be his subjects on the same 
>        terms as those which they had under Croesus, 
>        Having heard what they proposed, Cyrus told them 
>        a **story**. Once, he said, there was a flute-player who 
>        saw fishes in the sea and played upon his flute, 
>        thinking that so they would come out on to the land. 
>        Being disappointed of his hope, he took a net and 
>        gathered in and drew out a great multitude of the 
>        fishes; and seeing them leaping, "You had best," 
>        said he, " cease from your dancing now ; you would not 
>        come out and dance then, when I played to you." 
>        The reason why Cyrus told the story to the lonians 
>        and Aeolians was that the lonians, who were ready to 
>        obey him when the victory was won, had before 
>        refused when he sent a message asking them to revolt 
>        from Croesus. So he answered them in his anger.

it should be noted, that in the translation I was reading it used the word **apology** instead of story

Does anyone know if the original greek uses apologia? or was that an interpolation of the translator?

It does seem to make sense, if you construe that an apology, if taken by its archaic meaning, "an argument in defence of a position", acts like a destroyer of sorts, destroying the possibility of future alliances, and may fit in to other possible themes of culture shock when comparing customs and habits of the various Greek and Persian city states, especially in a context of an ambassador's audience with a King and its expected protocols etc.

I am well aware that in many instances Greek mythology uses personifications (as well as their parthenon of gods), treated as gods, they are nevertheless called by a simple word like for example: the gods "Sleep", and "Dischord".

Please, Please, Please!  Can someone (with a firm understanding of ancient Greek) tell me what exactly does the **WORD** *Apollo* actually mean?

Comment: Απο, _apo-,_ is a Greek prefix that conveys something superlative, usually a matter of a change of direction or an increase of dimension. I always think of a funnel when I see 'apo-' words. The unprefixed word is like the stem of the funnel, the tube. Add an 'apo-' and _whoosh_ it billows out into the wide aspect. Not sure if that helps at all with your research.

Comment: Your textual reference (Revelation 9:11) indicates that the Hebrew is the original source '_Abaddon_', _abad_ meaning destruction in Hebrew. '_Apollyon_' is the Greek translation of _Abaddon_, as the text records. _Apo_ / _luo_ is a destroyer - one who 'superlatively looses'.(Can't see a connection to _apo-logia_, though.)

Comment: Re '"an argument in defence of a position", acts like a destroyer of sorts' - that is a tenuous metaphor, and by tenuous I mean impossible. Anyway, the etymology doesn't support it: [apology = apo+logos](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=apology) vs [Apollo - "In spite of repeated attempts, there is no IE etymology"](https://www.etymonline.com/word/apollo)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, though the etymology of Apollo remains unclear, Greek popular etymology would agree with your link between Apollo and Apollyon. "The Greeks most often associated Apollo's name with the Greek verb ἀπόλλυμι (apollymi), 'to destroy'." And "Apollyon is the active participle of apollymi (ἀπόλλυμι, 'to destroy')". The Greek prefix [apo](https://www.etymonline.com/word/apo-) 'away from'/'descended from' is shared by Apollyon and apology.

Comment: re:@Mitch
The etymology **DOES** support it, apo- meaning away from, apology thus being an oxymoron in that in so attempting to win over to your side an oponent with your words, you are diverging from your ultimate goal.

Comment: What I was saying was that the etymology of the two, apology and Apollo, side by side does not support them being cognate.

Comment: I never said they were cognate.

Comment: Then this entire question is confusing. Why is the title 'Connection...' and a tag 'etymology'? Can you clarify in one sentence what you're asking for then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question appears to be about Ancient Greek, not English.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP requests Ancient Greek - this is not English...

Answer (score 0):

Abaddon and apollyon mean the same person in different languages on rev 9-11...so let's combine them... read rev 9-11 and you will see God is begging you to see this hidden message...combine both words by syllable and you get a bad dy poll on....the hidden message is the earth's dipole is bad specific to the on side or positive side...the bottomless pit is the center of the earth and as the magnetic field weakens, these locusts will soon escape their magnetic field prisons in the spirit world... earths magnetic field is weakening and moving... scientist say the poles are just flipping but that is an assumption...the magnetic field is rapidly weakening and it will get worse, not fix itself in a pole flip

Comment: Hence revelation 911.... Emergency situation earth God is trying to tell us

Comment: This is a tad less academic than the last answer.

Comment: Romans 13:1. Answers not really addressing the English language, rather being vehicles for expressing opinion (right as well as wrong), are frowned upon by the authorities. Please delete.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth By what authority do you judge others? Should you command us to worship at the altar of Apollyon would we be condemned for noncompliance? And when Apollyon commands all to accept his mark, you would see us sacrifice our salvation for your approval? Have you yet judged all the believers in the Bible that God rewarded for denying the false authority of leadership usurped?

Comment: @'Richard Morgan When in Rome, do as the Romans do.' 'When on ELU, don't violate the site rules unless they're manifestly unethical (find a licensed platform instead on which you can correctly share your views).' ELU expects practised members _to_ police the site, which includes judging poor answers. _I_ didn't introduce the ad hominem factor,  judging people rather than answers.